# Does Hume's objection to causality apply to human actions?

Tags: hume, causality

I heard the example with the kid and the toys from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WGn7-7caw8) video (TL;DW A kid who has only been playing with cotton toys gets a rubber ball and is surprised to see it bounce. His father is not surprised because he has seen a rubber ball bounce in many occasions, not because of some a priori law of causality) but it doesn't seem to apply in human actions. For example, if I see a ball coming towards me and I duck, I know the reason why I ducked (a ball was coming towards me). And I know that if it wasn't for the ball, I wouldn't have ducked. So, wouldn't it be fair to say that the ball caused me to duck?

Comment: I think it gets tricky because you have different levels of explanation and each one will point to a different proximate cause.

Comment: [Hume's objection](https://iep.utm.edu/hume-causation/) was not to causation as such, but to its inductive justification based on experience. The point was that we never see an actual causing, only a conjunction of (supposed) cause and effect. It is no different with human actions. All you know is that the ball gave you a compelling reason to duck, and that you did duck. You do not know that the former actually "caused" the latter other than by habitual inference. Perhaps, God monitors your mind, and it is he who actually caused the action when appropriate, not the ball and not you.